# Email sending doesn't work through Webform

Tags: emails

I'm trying to get drupal webform to send confirmation emails to logged in users after they validated a booking form. (Windows and IIS Server)

I monitored Drupal Log reports/dblog and got this:

```
Notice : Undefined index: und in eval() (line 22 in   C:\.....\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code)
```

Also, after submitting the booking form it gives this error: *Impossible to send mails, please contact administrator if problem persists.*

And to add, generally Mail sending works when tryin to reset my admin password.

Apparently I'm not the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're running your site on Windows. Either IIS or Apache?

Sending mail on windows based servers is a bit different. It cannot used php's normal method for sending mail if it were on a linux server.

You must configure an SMTP server in either your PHP.ini, or leverage the [SMTP Auth](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module and connect to an SMTP server.

PHP.ini setup:

- http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112190/php-ini-smtp-how-do-you-pass-username-password

Comment: Yes I am running it on Windows and IIS Server. Sorry for not claryfing that earlier. I'm trying your solution now will come back if it works out.

Comment: still not working unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't tell me a lot. What steps did you do exactly, what are you using for mail service, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I configured my php.ini file by changing the stmp config. (adding my email as sender).

Comment: Share your config?

Comment: Okay I installed the SMTP module and configured it correctly to send mails. I get shown in my Logs that a test email was sent but I dont get anything.////  SMTP -> FROM SERVER: @xxxxx
A test e-mail has been sent to xxxx@xxxxxcom. You may want to check the logs for any error messages.
SMTP.module is active.

Comment: Click the log everything setting in the SMTP auth and paste the output